# Google Mail API - parse get message headers

Tags: regex, node.js, gmail, email-parsing

Currently I am able to get a full message for a user, but I am trying to get to all the users that are on the "To" header of the message.  I am able to get the header value, but hoped there would be an sdk that would actually parse this header for me, as there are a bunch of different formatting of the user info.  I am using the node googleapis npm package.  If there is not something build in, is there a regex that I could use to parse this "To" mail header?

```
 const to = _.find(message.payload.headers,
                (header) => header.name.toLowerCase() === 'to');
```

'to' now has the value of the header, but this value is just a string of users all formatted in possibly different ways.  I need the user's name and email address of each user.

```
const users = [{name: <name>, email: <email> }]
```

Currently I am using a regex that is missing some possible formatting of this header.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Regexp may not be the best option for parsing an email `To:` field. I would recommend using something like https://github.com/andris9/mailparser instead.

Even if you don't have a raw copy of the email, it would be easy enough to reconstruct something similar by appending the strings for the headers and the payload.